# Promise and future, why does the main exit successfully?

Tags: c++11, promise, future

I started learning promise and future in C++11, But here I am stuck:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<future>
using namespace std;

void func(future<int> &ref)
{
    cout << ref.get();
}

int main()
{
    promise<int> prom;
    future<int> fut = prom.get_future();
    async(launch::deferred, func, ref(fut));
    prom.set_value(100);
    cout << "Exiting" << endl;
}
```

My understanding is, when we have `async` with `launch::deferred` it does not start a new thread.

So unless `ref.get()` executes `func` function won't `return` which will not happen since `promise` is set after that.

But my code exits successfully. Where is my understanding wrong?

IDE: VS2013

Comment: You are dropping the result of `async` on the floor. Since that's a deferred future, it never executes `func`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `deferred` async call simply stores the invokable object and parameters.

Nothing much happens until you call `.get()` on the **returned** `future`.

You discard that returned `future`, so your call to `async` was basically a noop.

Nothing else prevents `main` from finishing, so...